# What word would fit in the blank space?

Tags: word-request

The added time is relatively high on Monday and Wednesday (66 and 64 seconds __________).

Comment: **Respectively** if the ordering of the days and the ordering of the times are the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes you don't get a simple word. I love this website.

Comment: If the answer is suitable, please click **answered** so people looking for **unanswered** questioned won't be bothered by it.

Answer (score 2):

**Respectively** if the ordering of the days and the ordering of the times are the same.